# use webcore library in code using NDK in android

Tags: android, webkit, android-ndk

I am developing webkit and want to use it in android.
firstly I am trying to use android own webkit in code. so the steps I am using.

1. I have downloaded android (froyo) source code.
2. I have compiled that source code using android.mk and created all libraries (.so)
3. then I am taking webcore.so and copied it in libs/armeabi folder in code.
4. then I am loading this library using this code.

-

```
static {
         System.loadLibrary("webcore");
}
```

but that is giving **UnsatisfiedLinkError**. as If I am trying some other demo libraries that are working fine. so please suggest me that where is the problem?

Is there any problem of dependencies of other library used by webcore or something else?

Thanks Saurabh

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating your own apk file ? Are you running on the froyo SDK ?

Most possibly it's the webcore can not load the depended libraries. You can try to push the depended libraries to the /system/lib/ and have a try.

If you are running your apk on a device instead emulator, such as samsung or motorola phone , then, there's also another possibility that some functions you called in the webcore is removed or renamed by these vendors. I have fixed a lot of these kind of issues when I was developing a cross platform Browser.